# How to fiind out the missing records (ID) from an indexed [order] table in sql

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, gaps-and-islands

I have a table [Order] that has records with sequential ID (in odd number only, i.e. 1,3,5,7...989, 991, 993, 995, 997, 999), it is seen that a few records were accidentally deleted and should be inserted back, first thing is to find out what records are missing in the current table, there are hundreds of records in this table

Don't know how to write the query, can anyone kindly help, please?

I am thinking if I have to write a stored procedure or function but would be better if I can avoid them for environment reasons.

Below peuso code is what I am thinking:

```
set @MaxValue = Max(numberfield)
set @TestValue = 1
open cursor on recordset ordered by numberfield
foreach numberfield
 while (numberfield != @testvalue) and (@testvalue < @MaxValue) then
  Insert @testvalue into #temp table
  set @testvalue = @textvalue + 2
 Next
Next
```

**UPDATE:**

[image]

Expected result:

Order ID = 7 should be picked up as the only missing record.

**Update 2:**

If I use

```
WHERE
    o.id IS NULL;
```

It returns nothing:

[image]

Comment: What is your id column name in your table and what is the table name @mdivk - I'll provide an answer shortly (had this dilemma before and I have an answer for you)

Comment: Thank you very much and sorry to have missed your answer, it was my late night and I was sleeping.

Comment: Not a problem. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can try joining to a number table, which contains all the odd numbers which you might expect to appear in your own table.

```
DECLARE @start int = 1
DECLARE @end int = 1000

WITH cte AS (
    SELECT @start num  
    UNION ALL
    SELECT num + 2 FROM cte WHERE num < @end 
)

SELECT num
FROM cte t
LEFT JOIN [Order] o
    ON t.num = o.numberfield
WHERE
    o.numberfield IS NULL;
```

Comment: Thank you, but your query returns 0 records here. `CTE` is the full dataset, `[Order]` is a subset of the `cte`, tried also other joins, no luck. confused now.

Comment: My numbers table only covers to 1 to 999.  If your table doesn't have any missing numbers in that range, then my query would return zero records.  Please adjust the range to match your actual data.

Comment: I have only 1- 99 in the test table so it is fully covered and deleted a few in my test table, return nothing. :(

Comment: I tested my code locally and it seems to be working.  My guess is that you aren't running my code.

Comment: maybe I should have added the expected result in the OP, I Just posted a screenshot there and yes I am using your code. Thanks.

Comment: You used: `WHERE o.id IS NOT NULL` ... that's incorrect, and not what my answer has: `WHERE o.id IS NULL` ... you want the `IS NULL` case, because those are the numbers that didn't match.

Comment: actually for `WHERE o.id IS NULL` it returns nothing

Comment: [Check this working demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=ecfb910f02f09f00c1895a993e625d68).  There is something going on with your data perhaps.

Answer (score 1):

Since I didn't get a response from you, in the comments, I've altered the script for you to fill in accordingly:

```
declare @id int
declare @maxid int

set @id = 1
select @maxid = max([Your ID Column Name]) from [Your Table Name]

declare @IDseq table    (id int)

while @id < @maxid --whatever you max is
begin
    insert into @IDseq values(@id)

    set @id = @id + 1
end

select 
    s.id 
from        @IDseq s 
left join   [Your Table Name] t on s.id = t.[Your ID Column Name]
where t.[Your ID Column Name] is null
```

Where you see `[Your ID Column Name]`, replace everything with your column name and the same goes for `[Your Table Name]`.

I'm sure this will give you the results you seek.